# Geometry: Prove $PQ$ cuts $AB$ at the mid-point of $AB$

Tags: geometry

Let circle $(O)$ and 2 points $A,B$ lay on it. Call point $C$ is the mid-point on big arc $AB$. The line $d$ passes $C$ cuts tangent from $A,B$ at $D,E$ respectively. $AE$ cuts $BD$ at $Q$. $DE$ cut $(O)$ at $P$. Prove that: $PQ$ cuts $AB$ at the mid-point of $AB$.

I have tried Menelaus, let $PQ$ cuts $AD$ at $G$ so now we need to prove $G,Q$ and the mid-point of $AB$ collinear. So call mid-point of $AB$ is $F$. Now we need to prove:$$\frac{\overline{FA}}{\overline{FB}}.\frac{\overline{QB}}{\overline{QD}}.\frac{\overline{GD}}{\overline{GA}}=-1\Leftrightarrow \frac{\overline{QB}}{\overline{QD}}=-\frac{\overline{GA}}{\overline{GD}}$$

However, I can't see any relationship between $QB,QD,GA,GD$.
My  teacher said that Harmonic Division will help! Thanks for all your helping!
[image]

Comment: The description of the problem doesn't specify that $d$ passes through $C$, but your figure suggest it. It's that the case?

Comment: I'm sorry, $d$ passes through $C$

Answer (score 3):

[image: Diagram with T := AD x BE added.]

Let $T$ be the intersection of $AD$ and $BE$. Note that with respect to $\triangle PAB$, $PT$ is the $P$-symmedian. The problem, which is to prove that $PQ$ is the $P$-median, is now equivalent to proving that $PT$ and $PQ$ are isogonal in $\angle (PA,PB)$. But since $C$ is the midpoint of an arc $AB$ and hence $PC$ is a bisector of $\angle(PA,PB)$, this is equivalent to proving that $PT$ and $PQ$ are reflections in line $PC$.

Apply the dual form of the involution theorem of Desargues on the quadrilateral $DBEA$, with respect to point $P$. Noting that $Q$ and $T$ are the intersections of opposite sides, we now know that there exists an involution with pairs $(PD,PE), (PA,PB), (PT,PQ)$. However, the first two pairs already tell us that this involution is given by reflection in line $PC$ (noting that $PC$ is a bisector of $\angle(PA,PB)$). Therefore, $PT$ and $PQ$ are indeed reflections in $PC$ and we are done.

Comment: Why $PC$ is a bisector of $(PA,PB)$

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát It is a well-known fact that for an arbitrary triangle PAB, the two bisectors from P (internal and external) intersect the circumcircle of PAB (again) in the midpoint of an arc AB (either the arc that does not contain P for the internal bisector, or the arc that does for the external bisector). This is a direct consequence of the fact that equal angles in a circle cut equal lengths.
Now, since C is the midpoint of an arc AB, it follows that PC is a bisector of angle(PA,PB).

Comment: [+1] This kind of geometrical proof is under-represented in MathSE !